# Statistics for how many different authors post on categories of the arXiv

Tags: publications, arxiv, reference-request

I would like to know how many different authors have posted something on the different categories of the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/). Are there any statistics somewhere about this?

To be precise what I'm looking for:

- [Astrophysics](http://arxiv.org/archive/astro-ph): 2014 - 92348 authors
- [High Energy Physics - Lattice](http://arxiv.org/archive/hep-lat): 2014 - 45121 authors

If there are no such statistics, a pointer to a search engine that provides such data for different scientific fields would be a great help.

Comment: The arXiv supports the Open Archive Initiative http://arxiv.org/help/oa/index so in principle this is just a programming question. (Request all articles in Astrophysics, extract the author names, sort, kill duplicates, count.)

Comment: Also, it appears that the [arXiv analytics](http://arxitics.com/visual) website (note: not officially affiliated with arXiv) may perform visualizations of author contributions. But I haven't been able to get it to work in my browser yet, and as far as I can tell it may not have been implemented.

Comment: @WillieWong Can you turn your first comment into an answer, so that I can vote it up?

Comment: @jakebeal: done.

Comment: @WillieWong ... and done!

Answer (score 4):

(Now an answer by request.)

The arXiv supports the [Open Archive Initiative](http://arxiv.org/help/oa/index) so in principle this is just a programming question for

- Requesting and downloading the data for all articles in Astrophysics and dumping it locally in a usable format.
- Extracting the author information.
- Culling the duplicates.
- Counting the resulting entries.

If the first step is done right (by putting the information in a suitable database format) the other three will be more-or-less trivial.

Note however that name duplication would be a problem that is hard to solve, especially when some articles are listed with a "last name, first initials" format. Similarly authors who use more than one version of their names on arXiv (I'm guilty of that myself) can cause some inaccuracies to the computation outlined above. The mathematicians solve this "manually" by [employing 13 people and making this part of their jobs](http://blogs.ams.org/beyondreviews/2015/04/22/people-at-mathematical-reviews/), and I don't know if there can be a good programmatic solution until at least wide adoption of some sort of author ID (like ORCid) system.